# MRI and precession

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, precession

A lot of explanations of the quantum mechanics of MRI discuss the precession of a proton in an external magnetic field, for example here:
http://www.physicscentral.com/explore/action/mri.cfm

Doing the maths of this tells us that in a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}=B\mathbf{z}$ the state of a proton that began in the state with spin along the direction $(\sin\theta,0,\cos\theta)$ (that is, in the xz plane at an angle $\theta$ to the z-axis) will evolve in time according to $$|\psi,t\rangle=\sin(\frac{\theta}2)e^{\frac{i\omega t}2}|-\rangle\cos(\frac{\theta}2)e^{\frac{-i\omega t}2}|+\rangle$$ where $\omega=-\frac{2\mu_pB}{\hbar}$, $\mu_p$ is the magnetic moment of the proton and $|+\rangle$,$|-\rangle$ are the spin up and spin down states along the z-axis.

Now all the explanations I've seen basically seem to be along the lines of that there are two energy states, most protons are in the lower state and when the correct frequency is applied we excite them to the upper state.

My questions are:

1. How exactly does precession come in to this?
2. How can we say that most of the protons are in the lower energy state, when really they're all in superpositions of these energy states?